# SUM de una Medida POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, calculo

Es mi primera vez utilizando POWER BI, estaba intentando crear una Medida para realizar lo siguiente y me di cuenta que NO es posible.

```
ColumE = SUM(HorasTrabajadas)
```

Mi intención es obtener este valor que se ve en la tabla (3,58 que representa la suma de los valores de las filas) para aplicarlo posteriormente en un cálculo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es que la medida final quede de la siguiente manera:

```
Medida = Consulta1[HorasTrabajadas]*100/3.58
```

Pero lógicamente que el 3,58 sea una variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sin conocer el modelo de datos, me atreveré a dar una respuesta, que puede que acabe siendo solo aproximada.

La función `AVERAGE` te da la media. Si quieres obtener la media de toda una tabla debes eliminar los filtros del contexto, es decir los filtros que se puedan presentar en el informe.

Primero creamos una variable con la media (`AVERAGE`) total (con todos los datos de la tabla mediante `ALL`)

```
Medida = 
VAR media = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Consulta1[HorasTrabajadas], ALL(Consulta1))

RETURN
SUM(Consulta1[HorasTrabajadas]) * 100 / media
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, estoy utilizando lo siguiente - VAR divisor= CALCULATE(SUM(Consulta1[ColumnaHorasTotal]),ALL(Consulta1[ColumnaHorasTotal])), pero en lugar de darme el total que es 3.58 parece ser que me da un array y que divide la primera fila por 1.47, la segunda fila por 0.72 y la tercera por 1.39

Comment: Aclarar que ColumnasHorasTotal, como indica el nombre es una columna, que creé con los valores de la medida de HorasTrabajadas, para de esta forma poder hacer un SUM sobre esta columna.